# How to subset the readmitted cases from an inpatients’ table to calculate the total length of stay of the readmitted cases in SQL Server 17?

Tags: sql, r, sql-server

I am working with an inpatients' data table that looks like the following:

```
ID      | AdmissionDate |DischDate     |LOS |Readmitted30days 
+------+-------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|001    | 2014-01-01    | 2014-01-12    |11 |1
|101    | 2014-02-05    | 2014-02-12    |7  |1
|001    | 2014-02-18    | 2018-02-27    |9  |1
|001    | 2018-02-01    | 2018-02-13    |12 |0
|212    | 2014-01-28    | 2014-02-12    |15 |1
|212    | 2014-03-02    | 2014-03-15    |13 |0
|212    | 2016-12-23    | 2016-12-29    |4  |0
|1011   | 2017-06-10    | 2017-06-21    |11 |0
|401    | 2018-01-01    | 2018-01-11   |10  |0
|401    | 2018-10-01    | 2018-10-10   |9   |0
```

I want to create another table from the above in which the total length of stay (LOS) is summed up for those who have been readmitted within 30 days. The table I want to create looks like the following:

```
ID      |Total LOS   
+------+-----------
|001    |39
|212    |28 
|212    |4
|1011   |11 
|401    |10 
|401    |9
```

I am using SQL Server Version 17.
Could anyone help me do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what you want here. Other answers seem to have gone for: sum all patients who have been readmitted at least once. But maybe do you want to only sum up rows together if they are actually within 30 days of each other, otherwise you need to keep them separate? That is what it seems from the last two rows of your expected result (And in this case the `Readmitted30days` column is actually irrelevant to your query)

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Why do 401 and 212 appear twice in the results?

Comment: @Charlieface ,  This is exactly what I want and I realized that the Readmitted30days column is irrelevant. DO you think we could have some SQL code that would do this?– Mel just now   Edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Readmitted30days` column seems irrelevant to the question and a complete red herring. What you seem to want is to aggregate rows which are within 30 days of each other.

**This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.** There are a number of solutions, here is one:

- We use `LAG` to check whether the previous `DischDate` is within 30 days of this `AdmissionDate`
- Based on that we assign a grouping ID by doing a running count
- Then simply group by `ID` and our grouping ID, and sum
- The dates and `LOS` don't seem to match up, so I've given you both

```sql
WITH StartPoints AS (
    SELECT *,
      IsStart = CASE WHEN
          DATEADD(day, -30, AdmissionDate) <
          LAG(DischDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DischDate)
          THEN 1 END
    FROM YourTable
),
Groupings AS (
    SELECT *,
      GroupId = COUNT(IsStart) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DischDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM StartPoints
)
SELECT
  ID,
  TotalBasedOnDates = SUM(DATEDIFF(day, AdmissionDate, DischDate)),  -- do you need to add 1 within the sum?
  TotalBasedOnLOS = SUM(LOS)
FROM Groupings
GROUP BY ID, GroupID;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ae68ba9e215b7dee8619d8c5a6bda98e)

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly :

```
select Id, sum(LOS)
from tablename
where Readmitted30days = 1
group by Id
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
But  I think this code calculates the index admission's LOS. For example, if a patient with ID 01 was admitted on 2020/01/01 for 5 days and readmitted on 2020/01/15 for another 10 days, he/she will be flagged Readmitted30days = 1 on the index admission date (2020/01/01) , and the code provided will return total LOS=5.  I want to calculate the actual total LOS, which is 15 days.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use aggregation:

```
select id, sum(los)
from t
group by id
having max(Readmitted30days) = 1;
```

This filters after the aggregation so all `los` values are included in the sum.

EDIT:

I think I understand.  Every occasion where `Readmitted30days = 0`, you want a row in the result set that combines that row with the following rows up to the next matching row.

If that interpretation is correct, you can construct groups using a cumulative sum and then aggregate:

```
select id, sum(los)
from (select t.*,
             sum(1 - Readmitted30days = 0) over (partition by id order by admissiondate) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by id, grp;
```

Comment: Thank you, for the help.
This code provides the total LOS of inpatients who have been readmitted only. The one-time admitted cases are not included.
My intention is to calculate the total LOS of both admitted and readmitted cases, The total LOS of the one-time admitted cases =los. The total LOS of the readmitted cases is that is returned by this code.

Comment: @Mel . . . That is not how I interpret:  "I want to create another table from the above in which the total length of stay (LOS) is summed up for those who have been readmitted within 30 days. "

Comment: I think my question was not clear. Apologies for the ambiguity.